# Blank page when trying to configure payment methods in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, payment, system-config

I'm using Magento 2, when navigating to **Stores > Configuration > Sells > Payment Methods** it shows a completely blank page. I've already enabled dev mode and in other situations errors shows directly in the browser, in this case it only displays a total blank page.
Why this is happening and how i can fix it??
I've looked through the logs but found nothing. Even in the `/var/logs/report` folder, none file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking through exception and system logs, if not error is found then I would recommend disabling additional custom modules and enable them one by one to see which one is causing the issue.

If after disabling all additional modules you still have the issue then I'd delete all files under var and check file/folder permissions to make sure they are correct. Finally of all else fails check your sever logs

Comment: Did all this things, but no luck. By "delete all files under var" you mean to delete all contents from the htdocs/var folder??

Comment: Delete all files in magento var folder yes

Comment: I just want to be sure, in my var folder i have other folders like backups, cache, composer_home, generation, log, page_cache, etc. Should i delete all?

Comment: Delete cache, view_preprocess, generation, page_cache

Comment: Ok i've deleted all contents of var folder, but with no luck, payment methods config page still appearing as totally blank...

Comment: Under var/logs you should should now have a new exception and system log file check them

Comment: I've cheched system.log but found nothing related to my error. exception.log was not recreated after the delete...

Comment: delete your system.xml file if it comes back its possible you have not closed one off

Comment: where can i find this system.xml file that i have to delete?

Comment: It's local, i can't give you access for security reasons, sorry about that. Is there anything else i can try? I keep googling it meanwhile... Thanks for your help

Comment: have you installed any additional extensions? if so id consider disabling and enabling 1 by 1

Comment: i've installed only two additional extensions, i've tried disabling them one at a time a minute ago, but the problem still remains

Comment: disable both then delete cache and var/generation then check again

Comment: right, did what you said, no luck :(

Comment: Anyone have another idea??

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in my Magento 2.2.0, in my case the problem is related with an extra payment gateway module I installed (MercadoPago).
Try disabling any extra payment method module you have to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and in my case it was migrated settings.

It had migrated all the payment settings from the site, and that was causing a problem with Paypal/Braintree. I think the scope is not matched right between M1 and M2.

I removed all mentions of paypal or braintree from the core_config_data table and now things appear and I can configure again.

I guess I should add configuration to not sync all the config from these modules, which would be safest anyways